# Math Problem with Sets of words over alphabet

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, computer-science

I am looking for a book on Math Problems with words over alphabet.
For example:
Write in Set-theory Language a word:

ex.1 bbbbbbbb.....

ex.2 ba....

ex.3 bba.....

ex.4 bbba......

and so on
The formulation would be a word consisting out of b until the first transition of a.
But to learn i would need some exercise( with solutions if possible)

My solution so far is to create a automata and look for subwords which leads to the final state.

Comment: Might be worth looking a group theory text with a section on free groups.

Comment: `b+a*` in regex

Comment: You might take a look at formal languages.

Comment: There are a whole lot of textbooks on formal languages and automata, I can't really recommend any since I did not learn from English textbooks myself, but I'm sure you'll find what you're looking for among them.